# My database records all values ​to 0 when I post from fetch. Node.js mySql

Tags: mysql, node.js, fetch

**Here I have the backend code:**

```
router.post('/user', (req,res)=>{
 const {Id_document, Email, Password} = req.body;
 let user= {Id_document, Email, Password};
 let newUser = `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES (Id_document, Email, Password)`; 
 mysqlConnection.query(newUser, user, (err, results, fields) => {
   if (err) {
     return console.error(err.message);
   }
   res.json({ message: req.body, })
   });
 });
```

**I have also tried replacing the VALUES with "?"**

```
 router.post('/user', (req,res)=>{
 const {Id_document, Email, Password} = req.body;
 let user= {Id_document, Email, Password};
 let newUser = `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES (?)`; 
 mysqlConnection.query(newUser, user, (err, results, fields) => {
   if (err) {
     return console.error(err.message);
   }
   res.json({ message: req.body, })
   });
 });
```

**The values ​​that the database records are 0:**

```
  {
    "Id_document": 0,
    "Email": "0",
    "Password": 0
  },
```

Help, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: what does your `req.body` have as values?

Comment: {   
      "Id_document": 1,
    "Email": "email@gmail.com",
    "Password": 951
  }

Comment: this is the response: {
    "message": {
        "Id_document": 1,
        "Email": "email@gmail.com",
        "Password": 951
    }
}

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES (${Id_document}, ${Email}, ${Password})`

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{Id_document}, ${Email}, ${Password})' at line 1

Comment: How about ` `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES ("${Id_document}", "${Email}", "${Password}")` `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let newUser = `INSERT INTO User (Id_document, Email, Password) VALUES ("` + user.Id_document + `", "` + user.Email + `", "` + user.Password + `")`;
```

You need to build a complete Query string. By adding the user's values into the Query string.